# Move up and down in Jframe, how to make a lift?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a small program..When I execute it, I insert rows and columns and then when I click a button a matrix is appeared on the screen. My problem is that when the number of rows is bigger , I cant see all the matrix and other things that are below, and I can not move down in the JFrame. How can I do this? how can I add a lift, or elevator, to make possible to move up and down? I am not sure if it is called a lift ( the object at the right of the window that helps us to move up and down). Please help me...Thank you in advance.

Comment: The word you are looking for is scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "how can I add a lift, or elevator, to make possible to move up and down? I am not sure if it is called a lift ( the object at the right of the window that helps us to move up and down)."

Wrap the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

container.add(scroll);
```

Make sure you remove the table from the container, as a component can only have one parent container

---

See [**How to Use ScrollPanes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 0):

add(new JScrollPane(tableName));
you should put it in your constructor.

it worked for me, good luck :)